# Query of Queries variable scoping

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, qoq

Is it possible to scope variables when using query of queries? This works

```
return queryExecute("
        SELECT Title, Slug, Menu, MenuOrder
        FROM qryResult
        WHERE Menu = 'Y'
        ORDER BY MenuOrder
        ",
        [],
        {dbtype = "query"}
        );
```

This does not work. It throws an error

```
return queryExecute("
        SELECT Title, Slug, Menu, MenuOrder
        FROM local.qryResult
        WHERE Menu = 'Y'
        ORDER BY MenuOrder
        ",
        [],
        {dbtype = "query"}
        );
```

> Message   
> **Query Of Queries syntax error.**
>  Encountered
>   "local. StackTrace    java.sql.SQLException: 
> **Query Of Queries
>   syntax error.**
>  Encountered "local. at
>   coldfusion.sql.imq.jdbcStatement.parseSQL(jdbcStatement.java:590) at
>   coldfusion.sql.imq.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(jdbcStatement.java:547)
>   at            ORDER BY MenuOrder          ",          [],             {dbtype = "query"}          );

Comment: What does the 2nd sample do that constitutes, "does not"?

Comment: Try wrapping `local` within square brackets.

Comment: `[local].qryResult` works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LOCAL` is a reserved word in `ColdFusion Query of Query` and `SQL`.

So, wrap `LOCAL` with `square brackets[]` like this:

```
return queryExecute("
        SELECT Title, Slug, Menu, MenuOrder
        FROM [local].qryResult
        WHERE Menu = 'Y'
        ORDER BY MenuOrder
        ",
        [],
        {dbtype = "query"}
        );
```

**OR**

Use some other name for function local scope i.e.,

```
var newLocal = structNew();
newLocal.qryResult = queryNew("");
return queryExecute("
        SELECT Title, Slug, Menu, MenuOrder
        FROM newLocal.qryResult
        WHERE Menu = 'Y'
        ORDER BY MenuOrder
        ",
        [],
        {dbtype = "query"}
        );
```